# Does Skype for Business channel support Japanese characters?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

Does Bot Framework for Skype for Business support Japanese characters?

As shown in the attached screen shot, we are receiving all "?????"s for Japanese characters.

[image: Japanese characters]

Comment: How do you send it?

Comment: We've built our program on Ruby on Rails.
We put data into a Jason object and post it via https.

Alphabets are sent correctly. But Japanese characters all turn into "????"s.

Comment: What if you're sending `????` not properly encoded characters? How did you check that the data you send it correct? What encoding is it?

Comment: We printed the Jason object we sent.

In the object, the characters are normal Japanese characters, not "????".

Encoding is "UTF-8", which should support Japanese characters.

Answer (score 3):

Skype for Business can display Japanese Characters, like in my demo below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Dialog44558422 : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        await context.PostAsync("こんにちは、これはテストです");
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: sample]

You should really try to see how/what you are passing to the bot

Comment: Thank you very much for your support!

We've built our bot on Ruby on Rails referring to sample codes described here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview#create-bot

We put data into a Jason format and post send it like this.

Comment: puts "04:" + req.body.to_s
res = https.request(req)

When we print the object just before we send it like the code above, its content is correct Japanese characters, not "?????".

But when see them in S4B window, they all turn to "????".

We can't find out any reason for that.

Comment: I'm sorry but we won't be able to help you to solve your problem without more details, especially: a capture of what you send, the implementation of how you send it...

Comment: Could you please let us know what framework and language you used for your sample?

Did you use Bot Framework for Skype for Business?
Did you use Node.js?

Comment: It's Bot Framework yes (there is no `Bot Framework for Skype for Business`: it's `Bot Framework` and `Skype for Business` is a `channel`). The code in my sample is in C#

Comment: We've also tested with Bot Builder + Node.js. As far as we've tested, it worked ok before (on 5/12) with Japanese characters but now it doesn't work properly and the Japanese characters are corrupt the same as with Ruby on Rails + REST API.

Comment: I reported the issue to Microsoft and they've noticed the problem and fixed it. :)

They say the fix will be released by early in July.

Thank you very much for your support here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I reported the issue to Microsoft in mid-June, and they had already noticed the problem. They said:

> This is actually an issue in the sfb controller. This is fixed now and currently being validated internally. This is expected to roll out sometime next week or early in July.

The fix has now been officially released, and I can confirm that it solves the problem. Now Japanese characters are sent correctly:

[image: The image of Japanese characters sent correctly]

Comment: Can you add a link to where the fix can be downloaded? Or the name of it? That would make this answer more helpful to others.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

We don't need any update at our end. Microsoft have fixed the problem inside the s4b channel and released the fix already.