# Japanese characters sent from Skype for Business corrupt

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

Input Japanese characters from Skype for Business corrupt when our bot program has received them.

The problem happens with a certain PC. It works correctly with other PCs.

This is a log output when it corrupts. The input string is "こんにちは".
text"=>"縺薙ｓ縺ｫ縺｡縺ｯ"

This is a log output when it doesn't corrupt. The input string is the same "こんにちは".
text"=>"こんにちは"

We've implemented the bot with Ruby on Rails & Bot Framework REST API.

Does anyone know the cause and its solution of this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should wait for the fix of the bug your previously report (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558422/does-skype-for-business-channel-support-japanese-characters) or see directly with Microsoft on that

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

We think this problem may be a different problem from the problem I already posted.

In the previous problem, an output string to Skype for Business was corrupt.

This time, an input string from Skype for Business gets corrupt.

Comment: Yes but as discussed before not everyone was having the corruption even for the 1st bug. Here with the problem you mentioned we can only say "ok, but can't reproduce because you did not provide code AND your problem is not systematic", that's why my advise would be to contact directly the same person as previously

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

We've reported the issue to the same person who handles the previous issue at Microsoft. So far, we've not received a reply about it and we're not sure when we will. So we need to proceed inspections at our end so far.

We've found that when we see "こんにちは" encoded in URF8 with Shifh-Jis encoding, we see that garbage chars "縺薙ｓ縺ｫ縺｡縺ｯ".
We need to find out why it happens on some PCs and doesn't happen on other PCs.

Comment: We've found that from a PC that works properly, we can't send a message which contains only spaces. But from a PC that causes the problem, we can send a message which contains only spaces.
It seems that some client setting must be affecting the message in some way.

Comment: We've reported the issue to the Office 365 team.
According to their advise, we completely reinstalled the whole Office product. And the problem solved. This time the cause was at the PC side. The support person said something of Office component in the PC with the problem was broken.
Thank you for your advice here!

Answer (score 0):

We've reported the issue to the Office 365 team. Following their instruction, we completely reinstalled the whole Office product. And the problem solved.

The cause was at the PC side. The support person said something of Office component in the PC with the problem was broken.

Thank you for your advice here!